# Is there a range function to create a list of numbers?

Tags: applescript

I'm looking to make a consecutive list of numbers in Applescript. One could create such a list using a `repeat` loop, but that seems messy. Is there anything that works like this?

```
range from 1 to 10
-> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, answering the last question first, there is (using four more lines) a list-of-lists repeat loop:

```
set nlist to {}
repeat with n from 0 to 9
    set nlist2 to {n + 1}
    set nlist to nlist & nlist2
end repeat
nlist
--> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

Basically, if you repeatedly merge lists, you create a list of lists,
whereas...

```
set nlist to {}
repeat with n from 0 to 9
    set nlist to {n + 1}
end repeat
nlist
--> {10}
```

...would just result in the last number of the loop.
(Surely, there must be other ways, too.)

The closest one-line equivalent of ranges is probably "items 1 through 10" -but only for an existing list; example:

set rangeB to {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
set nlist to items 1 thru 10 of rangeB
nlist
-->{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

Regarding the title question, if it's a function you need, in Applescript they are called handlers, there is no preset range function, but you may create a customized range function for your task like this:

on range(a, b)
set nlist to {}
repeat with n from a - 1 to b - 1
set nlist2 to {n + 1}
set nlist to nlist & nlist2
end repeat
end range
--
range(5, 20)
-->{5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}

- And I think the real question behind the question (which I just recently had myself) was: "I'm coming from the world of spreadsheets, where are the ranges, where are the functions in AppleScript?" And the answer to that is: Ranges are now really lists, or items of a list, functions are handlers which you need write once, it's a bit extra work at first, but the upside is how easy then -and helpful- it can be to add customized functions, a whole new range (correction: list) of possibilities. And the AppleScript repeat loops are what the copy/paste down was in spreadsheets, essentially saying, in comparison: here is a function, I'd like to apply this to list A and it gets me list B with results, and repeat it again, from here to there. (Or non-stop.) Yes, copy/paste-down seems easier at first, and repeat with its "repeat with i" looks a bit esoteric at first, I agree, but on further consideration it is actually pretty straightforward, and there is really no way around it in so many coding situations. It's a core engine! "Eat, sleep, rave, repeat!" ;D And the repeat loops can be upgraded, again: offering more practical possibilities than the spreadsheet way of copy/paste-down.

Comment: Fantastically thorough answer. Thanks so much René!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

AppleScript is a very simple scripting language with a small core command set.

But it's extendible. Feel free to write a scripting addition or library providing this functionality.

PS: In AppleScript repeat loops are not messy at all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Solution without repeat loop:

```
generateRange(1, 10) -- generate integers sequence from 1 to 10

on generateRange(fromInteger, toInteger)
    "{" & (do shell script "jot -s ',' - " & fromInteger & space & toInteger) & "}"
    run script result
end generateRange
```

The same as single code line:

```
run script "{" & (do shell script "jot -s ',' - 1 10") & "}"
```